# Python NLTK text dispersion plot has y vertical axis is in backwards / reversed order

Tags: python, nltk, text-mining

Since last month NLTK dispersion_plot seems to have y (vertical) axis in reversed order on my machine. This is likely something about my versions of software (I am on a school virtual machine).

versions:
nltk 3.8.1
matplotlib 3.7.2
Python 3.9.13

code:

```
from nltk.draw.dispersion import dispersion_plot
words=['aa','aa','aa','bbb','cccc','aa','bbb','aa','aa','aa','cccc','cccc','cccc','cccc']
targets=['aa','bbb', 'f', 'cccc']
dispersion_plot(words, targets)
```

[image]

expected: aaa is present at the beginning, and cccc at the end.
actual: it's backwards! also notice f should be completely absent - instead bbb is absent.

conclusion:
Y axis is backwards.

Comment: if you have reversed order then maybe use `targets = reversed(targets)` or `dispersion_plot(words, reversed(targets))`

Comment: @furas that's not what I'm asking. Have a look at the example. Data is in the correct order - it's a bug in the graph library that shows bar in correct order, but LABELS in backwards order. Making graph misleading.

Comment: maybe you report it to NLTK's authors as error

Comment: BTW: I run code and sometimes it gives me `Y` in correct order, and second later it gives me `Y` in wrong order, and next time it show `Y` again in correct order. nltk 3.7, matplotlib 3.6.3, Python 3.10, python shell bpython 0.24, system Linux Mint 21.

Comment: BTW: there is source code for [dispersion_plot](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/draw/dispersion.html#dispersion_plot). Maybe you can find what can make problem. There is `revesed(words)` in source code.

Comment: I installed `nltk 3.8.1` and now it always show `Y` in reversed order. But if I uses `dispersion_plot(words, list(reversed(targets)))` then I get `Y` in expected order. But it still has problem with results for `f` and `bbb`. Maybe later I will try to find problem in source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found source code for [nltk.draw.dispersion](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/draw/dispersion.html#dispersion_plot) and it seems there is mistake.

```
def dispersion_plot(text, words, ignore_case=False, title="Lexical Dispersion Plot"):
    """
    Generate a lexical dispersion plot.

    :param text: The source text
    :type text: list(str) or iter(str)
    :param words: The target words
    :type words: list of str
    :param ignore_case: flag to set if case should be ignored when searching text
    :type ignore_case: bool
    :return: a matplotlib Axes object that may still be modified before plotting
    :rtype: Axes
    """

    try:
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    except ImportError as e:
        raise ImportError(
            "The plot function requires matplotlib to be installed. "
            "See https://matplotlib.org/"
        ) from e

    word2y = {
        word.casefold() if ignore_case else word: y
        for y, word in enumerate(reversed(words))  # <--- HERE
    }
    xs, ys = [], []
    for x, token in enumerate(text):
        token = token.casefold() if ignore_case else token
        y = word2y.get(token)
        if y is not None:
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)

    _, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(xs, ys, "|")
    ax.set_yticks(list(range(len(words))), words, color="C0")  # <--- HERE
    ax.set_ylim(-1, len(words))
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xlabel("Word Offset")
    return ax



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    from nltk.corpus import gutenberg

    words = ["Elinor", "Marianne", "Edward", "Willoughby"]
    dispersion_plot(gutenberg.words("austen-sense.txt"), words)
    plt.show()
```

It calculates `word2y` using `reversed(words)`

```
for y, word in enumerate(reversed(words))
```

but later it uses `ax.set_yticks()` using `words` but it should use `reversed(words)`

```
ax.set_yticks(list(range(len(words))), words, color="C0")
```

(or it should calculate `word2y` without using `reversed()`).

I added `# <--- HERE` in code above to show these places.

It may need to report it as a issue.

At this moment you can get `ax` and use `set_yticks` with `reversed` to correct it.
In your code it will be `targets` instead of `words`

```
ax = dispersion_plot(words, targets)

ax.set_yticks(list(range(len(targets))), reversed(targets), color="C0")
```

---

Full working code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nltk.draw.dispersion import dispersion_plot

words = ['aa','aa','aa','bbb','cccc','aa','bbb','aa','aa','aa','cccc','cccc','cccc','cccc']
targets = ['aa','bbb', 'f', 'cccc']

ax = dispersion_plot(words, targets)
ax.set_yticks(list(range(len(targets))), reversed(targets), color="C0")

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** I seems this problem was reported few months ago and they add `reversed()` in code on GitHub - and probably it will work in next version

[dispersion plot not working properly · Issue #3133 · nltk/nltk](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/3133)

[dispersion plot not working properly by Apros7 · Pull Request #3134 · nltk/nltk](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/3134)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @furas answer ❤️, I took it further and added an **if conditional that only reverses y ticks if they are indeed broken/backwards**. This means that once they fix the library bug (which is meant to be soon) the code will still work.

```
from nltk.draw.dispersion import dispersion_plot
targets=['a', 'b']
filtered_text = ["a","a","b"]
my_plot = dispersion_plot(filtered_text, targets, ignore_case=True)

# THIS IS NEW: if targets are wrong, fix them (reverse them)
if [label.get_text() for label in my_plot.get_yticklabels()] != reversed(targets):
    my_plot.set_yticks(list(range(len(targets))), reversed(targets))

plt.show()
```

(I fixed the graph library locally, and tested it with the new version, and the code works on both old-broken library, and new-fixed library)
[image]